# Converting Microsoft Office docs in Google Drive to analog Google Docs files

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, ms-office, google-docs

I'm trying to convert all Office files (ex. Word docs, Excel spreadsheets, PowerPoint presentations, etc.) in a folder on my Google Drive into their google doc equivalents.

I'm using the Advanced Drive Service in Google Apps Script to perform this task.

My implementation is below:

```
function convert() {

 var targetFolder_1 = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('Office Folder'); 
 var targetFolder =  targetFolder_1.next();                       
 var folderGoogify_1 = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('Empty Folder');
 var folderGoogify = folderGoogify_1.next();  
 var counter = 0; 

 var files = targetFolder.getFiles(); 
 var folderID = targetFolder.getId();

 while (files.hasNext()) {

   var nextFile = files.next();
   var blob = nextFile.getBlob();
   var fileName = nextFile.getName();

    var file = {
      title: fileName,
      "parents": [{
        "kind": "drive#parentReference",
        "id": folderID
      }]
    };

      file = Drive.Files.insert(file, blob, {
      convert: true
       });

     counter++;
     folderGoogify.addFile(file);
 }
}
```

However, at the last line I receive the following error:

```
Cannot convert [object Object] to File.
```

How can I adapt my code so that the converted file is recognized as a File, and not an Object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points :

1. The response of `Drive.Files.insert()` is JSON data. This is not file. So such error occurs. When you see the `file` using `Logger.log(file)`, you can see the JSON data.
2. In this case, `"parents": [{id: folderid}]` is `folderGoogify`.
3. You can directly create the converted files to the specific folder using Drive API. It is not necessary to use `addFile()`.

The modified script reflected them is as follows.

#### Modified script :

```
function convert() {
  var targetFolder_1 = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('Office Folder');
  var targetFolder =  targetFolder_1.next();
  var folderGoogify_1 = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('Empty Folder');
  var folderGoogify = folderGoogify_1.next();
  var counter = 0; 
  var files = targetFolder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var nextFile = files.next();
    var blob = nextFile.getBlob();
    var fileName = nextFile.getName();
    var file = {
      title: fileName,
      "parents": [{"id": folderGoogify.getId()}],
      "kind": "drive#parentReference",
    };
    counter++;
    file = Drive.Files.insert(file, blob, {convert: true});
  }
}
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the document with something like

`SpreadsheetApp.create("Example File Name")`

This will create the spreadsheet . You are trying to add info to a object, not a file, this will add it to a file.

[Google Sheets Script Error - Cannot convert [object Object] to Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41065587/google-sheets-script-error-cannot-convert-object-object-to-spreadsheet)